# sqlite - need to delete more than one row to add a new row when database is full

Tags: c, sqlite

When I try to insert new data to a full SQLite database, I need to remove much more than really needed.
I'm doing the following:

```
while(1) {
    do {
        status = insert_1_row_to_db();
        if (status == full) {
            remove_one_row_from_db();
        }
    } while (status == full);
}
```

The inserted data has always the same size.
When the database is full, removing only one row is enough to insert the new one. But after a while, I need to remove 30, 40 and even more the 100 rows to be able to insert one new row.
Is it the correct behavior of SQLite?
Is there a way to remove only what is needed and no more?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, its expected, there is no direct correlation between the actual size of the data itself and the size of the file on disk. Deleting a row will mark that region of the file as "free" for use in the future - if this were not the case the file would need to be reorganized & rewritten on every change. The [vacuum](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command explains this further. (That's not to say you should vacuum to mitigate this)

Comment: I'm not talking about the file size. I'm saying that to add a new row in the database, let's say 100 bytes, when the DB is full, some times removing 100 bytes is enough, but sometimes I have to remove 3000 or 5000 bytes.

Comment: But by "DB is full" you mean its file size is at some upper limit?

Comment: Yes I limited the file size with pragma max_page_count